# NiFi UnPackContent - what's the best way to discard the flowfiles if they cannot be unpacked

Tags: apache-nifi

I am using UnPackContent version1.9.2

I want to drill down into a zip file and find apples.txt file. I use a filter "apples\.txt" and it works successfully when apples.txt is present somewhere in the zip file.

But when apples.txt does not exist in the zip file I get an bulletin error "because it does not appear to have any entries; routing to failure" and as indicated the flowfile is indeed routed to failure.  This processor needs a 'failure' relationship.

I just want to discard the original flowfile if there is no match for the filter. How do I do that?

Comment: Is it possible to add flow screenshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Routing to failure relationship' if filter fails to match is a 'feature' of this processor. Can't do anything about it. It would be nice if they would provide a configuration switch.
So I filter on everything ".*" and RouteOnAttribute for "apples.txt", "oranges.txt" etc in the next level of flow. This reduces the number of possible 'failures' although it will still fail if there are no files at all in the incoming zip.

Answer (score 0):

In the settings tab of the UnpackContent processor you can check the box next to "Automatically Terminate Relationships" for failure. Which means you don't need an outgoing route for all your "failed" UnpackContent flowfiles. All of the failures will be automatically terminated and your processor can be in a valid state without an outgoing "failure" route.

You could also check the "original" checkbox to auto-terminate that outgoing route if you don't need the original file for further processing for example.

Almost all processors offer these kinds of Auto-Terminate options.

Comment: Thanks @Fudgy. I tried that but because the UnpackContent processor treats an unmatched result as a failure to unpack, it does not fail silently.  In UnpackContent processor's case it automatically terminates _and_ routes to failure so I still get the error bulletin.  In my application an unmatched result from the filter is a perfectly acceptable outcome.